# Best practice to create list item

Tags: android

I need to create a layout such as the one shown below for list view item. But I am trying not to just create it but I am also thinking about performance. I have tried to do this with the use of nested linear layouts with weight attribute but as I know it is not a good practice to use nested linear layouts with such attribute as it slows down performance of my application. Also I tried to use Relative layout but I haven't achieved the desired results. The most space shoud be given to the middle text views. 
Thanks in advance for help.

[image]

Comment: Is height of the whole item known/fixed? Do the textfields in the middle have to take exactly half of vertical space each?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand you correctly -or maybe there are certain requirements that you haven't said, but I think it should suit your needs:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="1">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:background="#8E7AE5"></RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:background="#E57A7A"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#D5E57A"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Top" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Down" />
</LinearLayout>


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:background="#8E7AE5"></RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I would be doing this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:andoird="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
andoird:layout_width="match_parent"
andoird:layout_height="48dp"
andoird:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum:1>


<TextView
    andoird:layout_width="0dp"
    andoird:layout_height="match_parent"
    andoird:layout_weight="0.25"
    andoird:text="Left textView"/>

<!-- Middle container -->
<LinearLayout
    andoird:layout_width="0dp"
    andoird:layout_height="wrap_content"
    andoird:layout_weight="0.5"
    andoird:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        andoird:layout_width="match_parent"
        andoird:layout_height="24dp"
        andoird:text="Middle Top textView"/>

    <TextView
        andoird:layout_width="match_parent"
        andoird:layout_height="24dp"
        andoird:text="Middle Bottom textView"/>

</LinearLayout>

<Switch
    andoird:layout_width="0dp"
    andoird:layout_height="match_parent"
    andoird:layout_weight="0.25"
    andoird:text="Right switch" />
```

This layout do not throw any XML warning about performance. And speaking of performance, you should use your ViewHolder in you ListView adapter. It helps alot.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="textview"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.50"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="textview"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="textview"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp">
        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/main_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Note :** i think using LinearLayout with weight we can achieved your requirement.